# How to Change rows in to Columns

Tags: sql

Please help me to solve this problem in SQl, my data is looks in the below format .

```
Row
------------
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
```

and the Output should display   below format.  Please help me for the below SQL Format.

```
Col -1   col- 2    Col--3
-- 
a          b         c
d          e         f
g          h         i
j          k         L
```

Comment: You need to provide more info and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Pivot` to do this.

```
SELECT [1] [Col-1],
       [2] [Col-2],
       [0] [Col-3]
FROM  (SELECT ( Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    ORDER BY Row) - 1 ) / 3 + 1 new,
              Row_number()
                OVER(
                  ORDER BY Row )% 3             rn,
              *
       FROM   Tablename) a
      PIVOT (Max(Row)
            FOR Rn IN([1],
                      [2],
                      [0]))piv
```